# predict in a loop using random forest with sklearn and pickle

Tags: python, machine-learning, runtime, pickle, random-forest

I'm using sci-kit learn on Python3.6 and I have some runtime problems for predicting in a loop with a random forest loaded from Pickle.

When I'm predicting from a random forest with 1 estimator (tree) the runtime is about 0.002 sec per sample. However, when I increase the number of estimators (>1) the runtime grows to 0.1 seconds per sample whatever the number of trees.

here is my code for saving the model :

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1, #or > 1 
            n_jobs=-1,
            random_state=2,
            max_depth=15,
            min_samples_leaf=1,
            verbose=0,
            max_features='auto'
            )

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

with open('classifier.pkl', 'wb') as fid:
    cPickle.dump(clf, fid)
```

and here is my code for loading the model and predict in a loop:

```
with open('classifier.pkl', 'rb') as fid:
    clf = cPickle.load(fid)

for s in samples:
    #my feature extraction method
    pred = clf.predict(feature) #feature is a 1D np array containing features computed for the sample s
```

I don't understand why the runtime isn't proportional to the number of trees and why it increases so fast. Is it a bug or am I using pickle in the wrong way?

Please, can you help me?

CB

Comment: Do you see the same problem if you don't pickle before predicting (I am guessing not?)?

Comment: Actually, I can observe the same problem before pickle when I do prediction successively on samples for more than one tree (still no problem with 1 tree..). Is it cause I'm predicting the labels successively on single samples (as a succession of 1D numpy array)? Because there doesn't seem to have runtime problem by predicting on all my dataset in one go (as a 2D numpy array)

Comment: It seems to take the same time for predicting one label for one sample as a 1D np array (~0.10 sec) than 2000 labels for 2000 samples as a 2D numpy array. But in my case, I have to predict labels in real time in a loop.

Comment: Maybe your feature-extraction method is doing something to increase the run time?

Comment: I don't think so because if I parse a 2D numpy array of pre computed features, and predict line by line, the problem is still here. It looks like sklearn takes a certain time to setup the trees first and does the prediction instantanetly after. This could explain why the runtime for prediction of a large 2D array is the same as a 1D array ? But it looks strange because I load the classifier only one time and this same issue occures without pickle too..

Comment: So it doesn't seem to be a Pickle-level issue either.